# pkg-config version of sdl2 is too low

Tags: haskell, sdl-2

I'm currently trying to get SDL2 for Haskell to work on Ubuntu but while trying to install SDL2 with cabal I get the following error

```
cabal: The pkg-config package sdl2 version >=2.0.3 is required but the version
installed on the system is version 2.0.2
Failed to install sdl2-1.2.0
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
sdl2-1.2.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

So it seems I do have pkg-config and I do have sdl2 but I seem to have downloaded the wrong version of libsdl-dev? I have the latest version, so is there a way for me to upgrade the pkg-config file?

Comment: what about - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713200/cant-install-sdl2-via-cabal?rq=1 - have you seen @Carsten's comment in the question?

Comment: I don't quite get your question - do you want to edit the cabal file and try if sdl2 >= 2.0.2 is also okay?

Comment: Have you tried getting a newer version of sdl https://launchpad.net/~zoogie/+archive/ubuntu/sdl2-snapshots should provide you with the necessary debs

Comment: hi, thanks for your responses.I wasnt sure exactly what to do after reading your comments but I knew I needed a different version of sdl2. Therefore, I updated to ubuntu 16, where I was successful in installing sdl2. Thanks!